# Query posts using less than

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, date-time

I have a working query using `pre_get_posts` that queries posts using the `status` post format that only shows those posts if it's in a date range using the UNIX time stamp. Only problem is that the post is still queried even if it's out of range.

I'm just wondering if there's a better way of querying posts using a custom field that also uses less than

Code:

```
$args = array('status_message' => 'alerts');
$status_alert = new WP_Query( $args );
$notice_startend = false;
$notice_start = false;
$duplicates = [];
while ( $status_alert->have_posts() ) :
    $status_alert->the_post();
    if ((get_field('status_type') == 'notice') && get_field('status_start_date') < date( 'U', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) ) && (get_field('status_end_date')=='')):
        $notice_start = true;
        $duplicates[] = get_the_ID();
    endif;
    if ((get_field('status_type') == 'notice') && get_field('status_start_date') < date( 'U', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) )  && get_field('status_end_date') > date( 'U', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) )):
        $notice_startend = true;
        $duplicates[] = get_the_ID();
    endif;
endwhile;

if (($notice_start == true) or ($notice_startend == true)):
<section class="notice-top">
foreach ($duplicates as $postID) : 
    if (get_field('status_type' , $postID) == 'notice'):
        <div class="notice-wrap">
            if (get_field('status_dealbox', $postID)):
                <div class="box-notice-left"><?php echo get_field('status_dealbox', $postID);?></div>
            endif;
            <div class="noc-notice-msg"><?php echo (get_post_field('post_content', $postID));?></div>
        </div>
    endif;
endforeach;
```

endif;

Comment: Thats a huge number of opening closing PHP tags, can you trim it down? E.g. `?><?php` can be removed as it doesn't do anything, and there's no indentation on large chunks of the beginning code, makes it super difficult to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
   $args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Obviously you could set the exact date from a variable.

More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query